# Se tenir à cheval du fosset - C'est quoi alors? (Mémoires de Casanova)

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire, terminologie, locutions, zoologie

On lit dans la préface des mémoires de Casanova le passage suivant:

> Mes succès et mes revers, le bien et le mal que j'ai éprouvés, tout m'a démontré que dans ce monde, tant physique que moral, le bien sort toujours du mal comme le mal du bien. Mes égarements montrent aux penseurs les chemins contraires, ou leur apprendront le grand art de se tenir à cheval du fosset.

Je ne trouve pas cette locution là dans le dictionnaire, non plus une explication raisonnable pour le mot "fosset". Plutôt, le Wiktionnaire donne "fosset" comme équivalent à "fausset". Mais "fausset" signifie une sorte de cheville qui a rien à faire avec un cheval.

Je crois bien comprendre le sens de cette phrase comme l'action de se tenir à cheval de fosset étant difficile et demandant de l'habileté. Mais, c'est tout.

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut donner ses lumières sur cette locution (origine, sens précis), et surtout sur le mot "fosset" ?

Comment: — Pour *fausset* : *https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/fausset* (et voir comment compléter le Wiktionnaire)  — Pour *fosset* : *https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fosset,* sans doute être capable de garder son équilibre en ayant un pied de chaque côté du fossé des contraires.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Fosset* est ici la [graphie ancienne](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/fosset) du mot fossé, qui subsiste encore aujourd'hui au Québec.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foss%C3%A9) (Fossé):

> REM.
> Fosset, subst. masc.,région. (Canada). Var. graphique. − *Tu seras content seulement quand t'auras bu ton chien-de-soul et qu'ils te ramasseront dans le fosset* (Guèvremont, Survenant,1945, p. 242).

L'expression *se tenir à cheval du fossé* signifie donc probablement, au sens propre « circuler à cheval au bord ou au dessus du fossé sans être désarçonné », et au sens figuré « s'écarter du droit chemin tout en maintenant son équilibre ».